# KeyError while executing pandas count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count

I am practicing using pandas module with a pokedex list. I am having an issue using **groupby** while looking for two columns. It works with one column and it gives the amount of pokemon in the list. It's easier to add a column to count it like this:

```
df["Count"] = 1
df.groupby(df["Type 1"]).count()["Count"]
```

Having

```
|Type 1         |
:---------------
|Bug          69|
|Dark         31|
|Dragon       32|
|Electric     44|
|Fairy        17|
|Fighting     27|
|Fire         52|
|Flying        4|
|Ghost        32|
|...            |
```

But if I want to add the Type 2 in the count it gives error:

```
df.groupby(df["Type 1", "Type 2"]).count()["Count"]
```

giving:

```
KeyError: ('Type 1', 'Type 2')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Type 1', 'Type 2'])['Count'].count()`

Comment: Added a more complete discussion on the allowable syntax calling `groupby()` below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have used a bad syntax for groupby function.
Try :

```
df.groupby(by=["Type 1", "Type 2"]).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
df.groupby([df["Type 1"], df["Type 2"]]).count()["Count"]
```

although for this case, you can use the simpler form:

```
df.groupby(["Type 1", "Type 2"]).count()["Count"]
```

`groupby()` does not support passing multi-column dataframe like `df[["Type 1", "Type 2"]]` but you can pass list of Series, like `[ df["Type 1"],  df["Type 2"] ]` or simply `["Type 1", "Type 2"]`.

Quoting `df` inside `groupby()` is necessary in the following case:

```
df["Count"].groupby([df["Type_1"], df["Type_2"]]).count()
```

In this case, the simple form is invalid:

```
df["Count"].groupby(["Type_1", "Type_2"]).count()      # invalid
```

It is because in this case, a pandas Series `df["Count"]` instead of the whole dataframe `df` is used to call `groupby()`, `groupby()` cannot recognize the columns `Type 1` and `Type 2` since `df["Count"]` is the pandas object being processed.